# How can I extract names from a concatenated string using Python?

Tags: python, list, names

Suppose I have a string of concatenated names like so:
`name.s = 'johnwilliamsfrankbrown'`.

How do I go from here to a `list` of names and surnames `["john", "williams", "frank", "brown"]`?

So far I only found pieces of code to extract words from non concatenated strings.

Comment: Impossible without knowing which first- and surnames you expect. E.g. 'Will', 'Williams', 'Liam' are all in there.

Comment: @timegb you could probably make use of Amazon's Mechanick Turk API's Python library. Humans can easily pick out the names but somehow I doubt this is what the asker is looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As timgeb noted in the comments, this is only possible if you already know which names you expect. Assuming that you have this information, you can extract them like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> names = ['john', 'frank', 'brown', 'williams']
>>> regex = '(' + '|'.join(names) + ')'
>>> separated_names = re.findall(regex, 'johnwilliamsfrankbrown')
>>> separated_names
['john', 'williams', 'frank', 'brown']
```